# Location or name of function in SciPy C source

Tags: python, scipy, cpython

I am trying to find some C source code for `min_or_max_filter` function from SciPy ndimage. The closest functions I found are in [this](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/81e636eb31c6a11c01c4ffeb880825a409ccb480/scipy/ndimage/src/nd_image.c) file (`NI_MinOrMaxFilter` for instance), but none of them are called `min_or_max_filter`. How does the name mapping between `.pyi` and `.c` files work?

Comment: That is not a member of the SciPy public API. You should not be using that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

generally there is a wrapper function that is responsible for mapping C types to python types to allow the development of C code independently from python.

this wrapper function is called [Py_MinOrMaxFilter](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/f102597b418c90020776d002278b2a068f5add85/scipy/ndimage/src/nd_image.c#L295) , which is [registered](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/f102597b418c90020776d002278b2a068f5add85/scipy/ndimage/src/nd_image.c#L1353) as `"min_or_max_filter"`,so it is [called in python](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/dde50595862a4f9cede24b5d1c86935c30f1f88a/scipy/ndimage/_filters.py#L1183) as `_nd_image.min_or_max_filter`, this function calls `NI_MinOrMaxFilter` internally after doing the necessary conversions from python types to C types.

note the underscore in `_nd_image` means it is a private module and can change between versions without notice.

using such wrappers is useful as this filter function is a pure C function, whose sole responsibility is to do the filtering while the wrapper's responsibility is to convert the types from python to C, therefore there's a good separation of responsibilities.